# the thick copper trace

Tags: high-speed

I need your help to find the answer for 2 questions:

1. What is exact name of the golden trace in the red area?
2. What is its purpose, and how to draw it in the PCB

Thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your picture is very poor quality but most likely it is the outline of a "screening can" that fits exactly over the "golden trace" and might have been envisaged as useful for reducing noise on some analogue components, maybe a radio receiver or sensitive analogue input.

As such it won't have an "exact name" but if you envisage the "can" fitting into the holes and being soldered down maybe you can think of a decent name.

Drawing it in the PCB is exactly the same procedure as drawing any component that doesn't have a standard library part.

Comment: You are right, in some RF design there are a shield cover the RF input components, and there are golden trace outline that fits under the shield. But normally it is rectangular. In this case it does not a rectangular. It seem to be like a trace that connected to ground and surround the group of component

Comment: It doesn't need to be rectangular - on one job I did, the footprint was hexagonal and, of course the "golden trace" was grounded in many places. It can be equally used for keeping noise out as preventing noise getting out.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a *via fence* or simply *fence* and it's meant for EMI shielding.